Invio dati da sensore DHT11 al Tangle tramite Testnet-2 e FireFly Shimmer
salve, sto cercando di inviare sulla rete di test di shimmer (testnet-2) i dati di un sensore dht11 acquisiti con adafruit-dht. Ho problemi con formato indirizzo FireflyShimmer, in pratica quando lo inserisco nel mio script python risulta con un formato non valido. Avrei bisogno di un modo per inviare sulla rete i miei detti per il mio progetto di laurea

Please write your questions in English. What problems do you have with the address? When creating addresses for testnet in the API, keep in mind that testnet uses cointype 1 and not 4219.
